# CSS Clip United States > Tennessee > Nashville from left?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET generated hyperlink for "select location". When the user clicks on it it takes them to a new page for them to select a new location, /change-location/default.aspx. It can be any country/state/city on earth:

```
"United States > Tennessee > Nashville"
"Australia > New South Wales > Sydney"
"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines > Other > Port Elizabeth, Bequia" etc
```

Normally the whole blue hyperlink displays fine on mobile portrait (320px wide less 10px margin each side).

However, when it is an unusually long link such as:

```
"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines > Other > Port Elizabeth, Bequia"
```

it wraps to the next line.

We only want to use up one line in total though.

How can I make it so if it is >300px in width, it clips from the left with elipses:

```
"... Grenadines > Other > Port Elizabeth, Bequia"
```

using CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used it once in my asp.net project.
Basically you need to use the direction, text-align, and text-overflow to get the ellipsis on the left.

```css
p {  
    white-space: nowrap;                     
    overflow: hidden;              /* "overflow" value should not be "visible" */   
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;  
    width:300px;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<p>"United States > Tennessee > Nashville"<br />
"Australia > New South Wales > Sydney" <br />
"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines > Other > Port Elizabeth, Bequia"</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to work well. I may be pushing it but does anyone know how to only display whole words? I'm just wondering if users may say what does "renadines" mean?

Comment: Or from a UX point of view, I wonder if people would think "... Other > Port Elizabeth, Bequia" would be more appropriate/clean in those extra long cases?

Comment: It may now be beyond the scope of the original question but I think I might need to use https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2118/bypass-graphics-measurestring-limitations to measure (strCountry + ' > ' + strState + ' > ' + strCity) and if that >300px then measure (strState + ' > ' + strCity) and if that >300px then just use strCity, still with Pratik's code though.

Comment: Welcome :), i am glad it helped you. @user1946932 If you want **intelligent** clips from the left then you must use back-end c# or JavaScript code to split string data with ">" as separator.